# Preflight request to Jira REST API failing due to missing headers

Tags: angular, http-headers, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to build an Angular 6 application that will interact with the Jira REST API.

My POST call for authentication fails on the preflight request (OPTIONS), according to the console due to a missing header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5555' is therefore not allowed access.`

I think I'm not adding the headers correctly.

Here is my code:

```
export class AuthenticationService {

  readonly headerDict = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  };

  readonly baseUrl: string = 'https://jira.domain.com'; //not the actual domain, duh

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {
  }

  login( username: string, password: string ): Observable<any> {
    const token: string = window.btoa( `${username}:${password}` );
    window.localStorage.setItem( 'currentUser', JSON.stringify( { authtoken: token } ) );
    const _headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders( this.headerDict );
    _headers.append( 'Authorization', JSON.stringify(token) );
    const requestOptions = {
      headers: _headers
    };
    return this.http.post<any>( `${this.baseUrl}/rest/auth/1/session`, {}, requestOptions );
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem( 'currentUser' );
  }
}
```

I think I'm adding the Headers wrong because when I put a breakpoint on the `requestOptions` in the actual POST, I'm seeing the following:
[image]

That doesn't really look like proper headers to me.

Answer (score 0):

try to append new header this way:

```
const _headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders( this.headerDict );
_headers = _headers.set( 'Authorization', JSON.stringify(token) );
```

hope this helps.